# how to separate numbers string to send bulk sms

Tags: iphone

i need to send sms to multiple numbers at a time.

to send sms i am using MFMessageComposeViewController.

i place a text field and pass that textfield text as recipients.

now i need to send it to multiple numbers at a time.

for that i think by placing the , as separator for mobile number.

eg:9292929292,92929292992,9292929292.

At the sending time i need to separate each and individual number.

How can i done this,

can any one pls help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a string separated by commas as your message suggests, you can just split the string on the commas and set the resulting array in your recipients property:

```
// assume messageController is your MFMessageComposeViewController instance
NSString* numbersToSendString = @"929292,929292,929292";
NSArray* numbersToSend = [numbersToSendString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"numbers:");
[numbersToSend enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL* stop){
  NSLog(" object %lu: %@", (unsigned long) idx, obj);
}];
[messageController setReceipients:numbersToSend];
// ... continue whatever
```

Comment: yes, i am getting "," also in the result like this  (
    1234567,
    9876543,
    1233432223
)
but i need to remove , also

Comment: @MaheshBabu: That's not the actual result you're getting, that's just the array formatted for you. If you dump the array you'll see. Try this to view the array: [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL* stop){ NSLog(@"item %lu: %@", (unsigned long) idx, obj }]; You'll see there are no ',' attached to any number

Comment: it is not understandable if u done mine can u please edit your answer and paste there

Comment: @MaheshBabu: This will print out each object by itself. The commas you see are part of the description formatter on arrays to make it easier for you to see what elements any NSArray contains. They're not really part of the element data.

Comment: thank u very much jason coco,i have a dought we need to add for loop to send sms to multiple numbers at a time or just passing array elements as reception

Comment: @Mahesh : Hello Sir may you tell me how to fetch the multiple no. in your static format no. as NSString* numbersToSendString = @"929292,929292,929292"; if i m reading direct values from Address book of iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Use the NSString method componentsSeparatedByString, like below,

```
NSString *list = @"Norman, Stanley, Fletcher";
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

Comment: yes, i am getting "," also in the result like this  (
    1234567,
    9876543,
    1233432223
)
but i need to remove , also

Comment: If you directly NSLog the resultant array it will print each object comma separated only. So you have to take each object separately by iterating through the array and send the sms.