# How to add numbers in sms?

Tags: iphone

Hi
    I am working on an application. In my application user has to send message to the number which he/she had selected from the contact list.

```
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {

        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12345678", @"87654321",nil];

        controller.recipients=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name"];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
```

This is what i written. But selected numbers are in another ViewController. How it is possible? Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: Please explain your question a bit more.. help us is help you!

Comment: I have ViewController name contact. In that view controller we can select 5 phonenumbers from contactlist. when i press send button the message should send to the selected numbers. And this code is another viewController. How to add recipients in controller.recipient?

Comment: you need to create an array and pass this array to another view contorller... and you can use that array in another view controller to add recipients..

Comment: Can you tell me how? or sample code?

Answer (score 0):

HI,

Use the below code ...

```
//Assume messageController is your MFMessageComposeViewController instance
NSString* numbersToSendString = @"929292,929292,929292";
NSArray* numbersToSend = [numbersToSendString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"numbers:");
[numbersToSend enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL* stop){
  NSLog(" object %lu: %@", (unsigned long) idx, obj);
}];
[messageController setReceipients:numbersToSend];
// ... continue whatever
```

More ON [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743410/how-to-separate-numbers-string-to-send-bulk-sms) post
\

**EDITED:**

```
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
 MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
 picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;
 NSString *bodyString = nil;

 NSString* numbersToSendString = @"929292,929292,929292";
 NSMutableArray* toRecipients = [numbersToSendString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];      
[picker setRecipients:(NSArray *)toRecipients];
[toRecipients release];

bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Message body"];
[picker setBody:bodyString];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

Comment: MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

Comment: if i directly write number there it will send. But i don't want that.I have ViewController name contact. In that view controller we can select 5 phonenumbers from contactlist. when i press send button the message should send to the selected numbers. And this code is another viewController. How to add recipients in controller.recipient?

Comment: @Akhila: As per your requirement, Put the whole edited code (you also need to modified the edited code a bit ) in a function which will have a NSArray parameter (containing all number). and call it from where ever you need (As per your requirement).

Comment: @Jhaliya warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSString *', expected 'struct NSMutableArray *' when passing argument 1 of 'setRecipient:' from distinct Objective-C type    warning: class 'ContactViewController' does not fully implement the 'MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate' protocol

Comment: @Akhila :Please see code carefully , you can only pass NSArray as an argument to  setRecipients: function,  And the warning you get because you are passing NSString to setRecipients: plz check once ....... NSMutableArray* toRecipients = [numbersToSendString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];      
[picker setRecipients:(NSArray *)toRecipients];

Comment: @Jhaliya 64: warning: incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct NSArray *', expected 'struct NSMutableArray *'

Comment: @ Akhila: Hi try with ... [picker setRecipients:toRecipients];

Comment: @Jhaliya it is showing same warning but if i remove Mutable from NSMutableArray. only NSArray it is not showing warning now.What to do?

Comment: @ Akhila: ok , i got you . Actually we can overlook for this warning because NSArray is the base class for NSMutableArray .. So try with avoiding the warning  ...